# C# Unit Test Project in Visual Studio 2013 only showing coverage for Unit Tests.

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I created a new unit test project in Visual Studio and added the project under test to the references.

The test methods themselves create an object of the class under test and calls a method in that class. I hit F12 on the class name or method name in the test and it brings me to class itself. It also throws errors when I remove the reference to the project.

But when I run the code coverage I only see the test.dll and coverage of 100%. And there's no project.dll in the test\bin folder.

Has anyone any ideas why it may not be building the project.dll ?

Comment: Coverage is only calculated for projects that have the creation of debug symbols turned on by default. Is your current project configuration is not creating `.pdb` files?

Comment: The project is creating .pdb files yes. There's .dll, .pdb and .tlb files in the project bin. They're just not in the test bin which is where I assume they should get built to when added as a reference ?

Comment: They should be... Is the reference set to copy-local?

Comment: Yep, set to copy local.

Comment: If you copy the files manually, does the coverage appear? Does the project under test have any post-build actions that copy the output files to a non-standard location?

Comment: No, it still doesn't show up when I manually copy them over and nothing non standard in the post build.

Comment: Apart from setting the msbuild logs to detailed and going through them to see what's going wrong, I'm out of quick tips, unless you can share the solution.

Comment: You mention a 'tlb' what's the type of the project under test... Are you loading the assembly through COM?

Comment: I can't share it unfortunately. I'll look into the msbuild logs and see if I spot anything. Thanks for your time.